# Can't find a way to remove/restart a DLLs state in memory from my windows service

Tags: c#, dll, .net-4.0

I am using a 3rd party DLL which reads from a file when it is first used, but never checks it for changes.  My idea was to just load the DLL in an AppDomain and unload the DLL after I make my first call - so I wipe out the state of the DLL with every call (more or less).

```
AssemblyName name = AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(@"C:\fake.dll");
AppDomain newDomain = AppDomain.CreateDomain("DomainName");
Assembly lib = newDomain.Load(name);

...
//Use the Assembly

AppDomain.Unload(newDomain);
```

This block of code can be run multiple times a second - inefficient, but its my only option with this DLL for now...

The problem is the DLL's memory seems to exist even in other AppDomains that I create - it is still using the same value it found when it read the file the first time (and it never checks again).  The only way I can get the DLL to read the file again is to restart the service.

Do I not understand the AppDomain or should I attack this from a different angle?

**Edit**: The problem of loading the DLL into my own domain has been address using a MarshalByRefObject class (thank you!), but I don't want it to be cross domain.  I want this DLL to live and die in this one AppDomain - would the Unload method be enough to squash any hopes of this DLL's state showing up in another AppDomain?

Comment: I don't quite understand why you need to unload the DLL after the first call every time. Is there any way you could clarify a bit more?

Comment: You could use dotTrace or some other .net decompiler to see which method sets the state and then call it via reflection.

Answer (score 3):

If you are directly using objects from the dll in your "//Use the Assembly" code, then you've pulled the dll into the current AppDomain as well as the new one.  That means that you haven't really achieved your goal.

You'll need to use reflection to use the classes and methods loaded into the new AppDomain without pulling the dll into the original AppDomain.

Answer (score 3):

This line:

```
Assembly lib = newDomain.Load(name);
```

causes the assembly to [also be loaded in the *current* AppDomain](http://lsd.luminis.nl/load-and-unload-assembly-in-appdomains/) because the `Assembly` class is marked as `[Serializable]`, not `MarshalByRefObject` and so it is serialized across the AppDomain boundary:

You can create your own [`MarshalByRefObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.marshalbyrefobject.aspx) object to proxy the calls into another assembly. See the example in MSDN for more information. But the basic idea is something like this:

```
public class Worker : MarshalByRefObject, IWorker
{
    public void DoWork() 
    { 
        // Load the assembly here. This code will run in the AppDomain
    }
}

public interface IWorker
{
    void DoWork();
}


public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        AppDomain ad = AppDomain.CreateDomain("New domain");

        // This line creates a proxy to your worker.
        IWorker remoteWorker = (IWorker) ad.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(
            Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName,
            "Worker");

        remoteWorker.DoWork();

        ad.Unload();
    }
}
```

You can even take this a step further and have your Worker class implement an interface and put that in a shared assembly.

Comment: +1 for info on Load; it's a bit misleading that the instance AppDomain.Load method is actually the same behavior as the static Assembly.Load method.

Comment: @Dan Bryant: Actually my wording may been a bit misleading: that line causes the Assembly to be loaded into *both* AppDomains. I've updated my answer to hopefully make it more clear.

Comment: @MarkByers: Thanks for your answer.  However, I've found that I'm experiencing the same issue... I should be calling AppDomain.Unload(ad) right?

Comment: @Ryan, Note that, if you want to Unload, the 'Worker' class cannot be in the dynamically loaded assembly; it needs to be in a separate assembly that both the original assembly and the dynamically loaded assembly reference.  It's typical to use an interface for this purpose (so you can put the actual MarshalByRefObject in your dynamically loaded assembly.)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what's going on in the `//Use the Assembly` section here, but I suspect that what you are doing is inadvertently loading the assembly into the *calling* AppDomain, e.g. your main application's appDomain.

What you want to do is put all of the code that uses that DLL into an assembly all by itself, ideally with a very simple method on a class inheriting from MarshalByRefObject to kick it off, like this:

```
public class StartErUp : MarshalByRefObject {
    public void RunThatOtherDll() { ... }
}
```

then load that class using AppDomain.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap().  It is important that your class inherits from MarshalByRefObject, because that tells the CLR to create a cross-appdomain proxy for it, rather than trying to serialize (copy) it across AppDomains.